# AngularJS - Refresh after POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

What is the correct way to refresh content after a http POST request in Angular?

```
//controller.js
var hudControllers = angular.module('hudControllers', []);

hudControllers.controller('PropertyDetailsCtrl', 
  ['$scope','$window','$http', function ($scope,$window,$http) {

   //I want to reload this once the newCommentForm below has been submitted
   $http.get('/api/comments')
    .success(function(data) {$scope.comments = {"data":data};}})
    .error(function(data) {...);

   $scope.newCommentForm = function(){

      newComment=$scope.newComment;
      requestUrl='/api/comments';
      var request = $http({method: "post",url: requestUrl,data: {...}});
      request.success(function(){
        //How do I refresh/reload the comments?
        $scope.comments.push({'comment':'test'}); //Returns error - "TypeError: undefined is not a function"
      });
  };

}]);

//template.ejs
<div class="comment">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="comment in comments.data">{{comment.comment}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways you can do it. still I want to show you simplest way (according to your needs).

lets say you have 'first.html' page and 'PropertyDetailsCtrl' is associated with it.
Now, in html you can write like this,

```
 with very first-div 
 <div ng-controller="PropertyDetailsCtrl" ng-init="initFirst()"> 
.... Your page contents...
</div>   (This will initialize your controller and you will have execution of your first method 'initFirst()'.
```

at your .js side....

```
var hudControllers = angular.module('hudControllers', []);

hudControllers.controller('PropertyDetailsCtrl', 
  ['$scope','$window','$http', function ($scope,$window,$http) {

   //I want to reload this once the newCommentForm below has been submitted
$scope.initFirst=function()
{


   $http.get('/api/comments')
    .success(function(data) {...})
    .error(function(data) {...);

        //You need to define your required $scope.....

     $scope.myVariable=data;

 };
```

Now at appropriate time (You know when) your below method gets called.

```
   $scope.newCommentForm = function(){

      newComment=$scope.newComment;
      requestUrl='/api/comments';
      var request = $http({method: "post",url: requestUrl,data: {...}});
      request.success(function(data){
        //How do I refresh/reload the comments?
             //without calling anything else, you can update your $scope.myVariable here directly like this


       $scope.myVariable=data


      });

      //or else you can call 'initFirst()' method whenever and wherever needed like this,

    $scope.initFirst();


  };

}]);
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: welcome matt. ahead, you'll have many queries related to Angularjs. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if there is ONE correct way, but you can call $location.path() on success.

```
request.success(function(){
    $location.path('your path');
});
```

To view the added comment (which apparently is what you want), you could use :

```
request.success(function(response){
    $scope.comments.push(response.data);
});
```

Your content would refresh automatically on the page, if you're using angular expressions and a ng-repeat.

Comment: I think OP doesn't ask for a page refresh, just a comment reload.

Comment: Edited to reflect that.